# copy my exchange server settings password

Tags: settings, exchange, password

The password field under "exchange server settings" is blocked out. I want to add my business email to another phone. Is there any way to reveal the password?

Thanks.

Comment: you don't know the password to your business email address? @_@

Comment: well, the one I regularly use doesn't work. Meh, I'll ask my boss, hopefully she knows.

Comment: I'm sorry if that came out rash, but hopefully there should be a way to reset that password through your Sys Admin (or better if your boss knows).

Comment: don't understand why it would block the password to begin with. most apps you can click a "show password" button.

Comment: Pretty sure it's there for security reasons, all the more since that is business email.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the stock `Email` app, there is no way to show the password. This is for your privacy and security. You don't want people to be able to see your password if you lost the phone, especially if don't use a PIN- or password-enabled lockscreen.

The best way to resolve this issue is to contact your company's IT Support, and request for a password change.